# OWIN MixedAuth User.Identity.GetUserId returns null

Tags: owin, mixed-authentication

I am using [OWIN-MixedAuth](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/OWIN-MixedAuth) to authenticate website users. Running it locally with VS2015 on a Win10 mahine everything is fine. Deploying it to the productive Windows 2008 R2 server within an AD domain the User.Identity isn't a ClaimsIdentity, it is a WindowsIdentity missing the NameIdentifier claim and GetuserId returns null.

In Startup.Auth.cs I set the following cookie options. The login path points to "account/windowslogin" as recommended [here](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/OWIN-MixedAuth/issues/8#issuecomment-149985443).

```
    var cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoginPath"]),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, IdentityUser, Guid>(
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            async (manager, user) => await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
            (id) => new Guid(id.GetUserId())),
        }
    };
```

Any ideas why IIS 7.5 is acting differently here?

Cheers
Bernd